# Python get timezone from offset string

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, timedelta

I'm new to datetime in Python and I have a date string in this format `'05/18/2022 12:00:55'`. And a separate offset string like this `'-06:00'`.
I'm trying to make a final datetime object which is timezone aware based on the offset string.
Expected Result `2022-05-18 06:00:55-06:00`

**Try 1** - Add the offset string to the datetime string and convert to datetime object. this results in `2022-05-18 12:00:55-06:00` and not `2022-05-18 06:00:55-06:00`

```
date_string = '05/18/2022 12:00:55'
timezone_string = '-06:00'
date_string_2 = datetime.strptime(date_string + timezone_string, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S%z')
print(date_string_2)
```

**Try 2** - Play around with the tzinfo property but this throws an error

```
date_string = '05/18/2022 12:00:55'
timezone_string = '-06:00'
date_string_2 = datetime.strptime(date_string, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S%z')
date_string_2.replace(tzinfo=timezone_string)
print(date_string_2)
```

Could anybody please help and/or point me in the right direction with this. Thank you.

Comment: For clarity, what you have is an offset from UTC, not a time zone (in a geographical sense).

Comment: And for my understanding, your `date_string` represents UTC?

Comment: Yes exactly. date_string represents UTC and I have an offset from UTC as a string that defines my expectation for the final date representation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you'll want to parse the date_string to datetime object, replace tzinfo with UTC, then convert with astimezone to UTC-6. For that, you parse timezone_string to datetime object as well, but just use its tzinfo.

EX:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone

date_string = "05/18/2022 12:00:55"
timezone_string = "-06:00"

dtobj_utc = datetime.strptime(date_string, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S").replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
dtobj_tz = dtobj_utc.astimezone(datetime.strptime(timezone_string, "%z").tzinfo)

print(dtobj_tz.isoformat(" ", timespec="seconds"))
# 2022-05-18 06:00:55-06:00
```